# Independent sets with few neighbours

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, trees, discrete-optimization, bipartite-graphs

I am looking for references about the following problem.

> Given a (connected) bipartite graph $G$, find an independent set $M$ minimizing the ratio $|\partial M|/|M|$.

Here, $\partial M$ denotes the set of neighbours of $M$.
An independent set is a set $M$ of vertices such that $(\partial M)\cap M = \emptyset$.

More specifically, I am looking for information about the class of bipartite <del>graphs</del> *trees* $G= (A\,\dot{\cup}\, B \,, E)$ for which $A$ is *the unique solution* to the problem above.

Examples of such graphs include lines with an odd number of vertices, or, more generally, trees in which every $b\in B$ has degree two.

*[Edit: Specified the question, and added an example.]*

Comment: When $|A|=|B|$, the bipartite graph $G$ is in this class iff it has a perfect matching. Generalizing this, when $|A|=k|B|$ for an integer $k$, $G$ is in this class iff it can be covered by disjoint copies of $K_{k,1}$. Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: @MishaLavrov: In principle yes, but not exactly. Actually, my interest is mainly in graphs for which $A$ is _the unique_ solution to the problem (made an edit to explain this). But any references treating the problem, in some form, would be of interest. I'm not a graph theorist, and do not know where to look.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423653/independent-sets-with-few-neighbours